# How to set phpdocumenter INFO displaying?

Tags: phpdoc

I'm using phpdocumenter, but since I puppetized it again I get for every file it inspects a line saying:

```
[2014-07-23 09:12:24] phpDocumentor.INFO: Parsing /home/kramer65/my-project/ClassMapper.php [] []
```

Although I don't think it does any harm, it's really annoying because it clogs up the output. Any ideas how to turn that off?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

No... phpDocumentor 2.x does not have a "--quiet" option like 1.x had.

Comment: I might be wrong about this.  phpdoc 2.x seems to be accepting "--quiet", although it's not documented as an available option.